# Install Ubuntu server on one computer, then soon as possible control it (via terminal) through another

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-server

I tried to set up a home network the other day, and wanted to set my old computer up as a file server. So, I installed ubuntu server on it. Once installed and logged in, I realsied that some of the keys are not working. Mainly the forward slash and right arrow key. The forward slash is a real pain as I can't type in file paths. So, if I can quickly set it up enough on the network, install whatever I can, then login to it from the other computer (which has a fully working keyboard) then I can do all operations from that keyboard. The problem is I'm very new to setting networks and servers let alone trying to do this. If someone could advise what tool(s) I may need to do this, maybe even steps required, from fresh installation I'd be most grateful. Thanks

Comment: offtopic on SO; this should be asked on [su]

Answer (score 0):

After installation of the server, the first thing you should do is to install ssh on it:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

More information about installation of SSH on the server can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/openssh-server.html. Now you can ssh "into" your server from the client PC. If the PC is running Windows, then try Putty. If the PC is running Linux/OSX, then simply ssh to your server from the console/terminal:

```
ssh username@ip_of_server
```